# Mapping existing data in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, razor

I'm starting to learn some `AngularJS` and am trying to determine its practicality when working along side `ASP.NET` `MVC`.

Let's say I have a view which displays beers from a repository in a table. I could output the information in two ways.

**1.Using MVC's Razor Engine**

Here, the model containing the beers is processed on the server and the html page rendered.

```
<h3>Rendered using Razor!</h3>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Colour</th>
            <th>Tasted?</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var beer in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@beer.Name</td>
                <td>@beer.Colour</td>
                <td>@beer.Tried</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**2.Using Angular repeat**

Here, the HTML is returned straight away and angular performs a `AJAX` call to the controller to retrieve its model. After it has that data it outputs it into the table.

```
<h3>Rendered using Angular!</h3>
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Colour</th>
            <th>Tasted?</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr data-ng-repeat="beer in model">
            <td>{{ beer.Name }}</td>
            <td>{{ beer.Colour }}</td>
            <td>{{ beer.Tried }}</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller

```
angular.module('BeerController', [])
.controller('BeerCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.model = {};

    $http.get('/Beer/GetBeers').success(function (data) {

        $scope.model = data;

    });


}]);
```

**My Question**

Is there a way to use the Razor engine for the initial load of the data and Angular for everything else (paging calls, searching etc.)? In other words, **how do I bind existing html to a controllers model in AngularJS?**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Colour</th>
            <th>Tasted?</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Fosters</td>
                <td>Gold</td>
                <td>True</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Becks</td>
                <td>Amber</td>
                <td>False</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cobra</td>
                <td>Gold</td>
                <td>True</td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You wouldn't.. you would make the AJAX call and display the data. You *could* use `ng-init` on values from the server, or create a constant with stringified data, parse it in your controller, but that's a bit overkill

Comment: The whole point of Angular is that it replaces any server side templating such as Razor. All that the server must do is expose a JSON REST API and a single endpoint serving the initial html of the SPA application.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Wouldn't they work well together? Using Razor to initially load the html and data and expose a REST API for everything else? This would reduce the number of request to the service

Comment: @heymega -- I think you'd just be creating more work trying to mesh the server-side templating into the client.

Comment: @tymeJV Yeah I think you may be right

Answer (score 2):

In your MVC Controller

```
    public ActionResult Index()   
    {

    var model =.....    

    //optional
    JsonSerializerSettings jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() };

    ViewBag.data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, Formatting.Indented, jsonSerializerSettings);

return View()

    }
```

In your view Index.cshtml

```
...
@section Scripts { 

//make sure that all anular scripts are loaded before that
<script>
angular.module('BeerController').service('dataService', function () {

var data= @Html.Raw(ViewBag.data);

return  {

data:data

}

});
...
</script>

}
```

Angular Part:

```
angular.module('BeerController', [])
.controller('BeerCtrl', ['$scope', '$http','dataService', function ($scope, $http,dataService) {

// now you can get data from your dataService without extra trip to your server
    $scope.model = dataService.data
....
```

}]);